# How come PostgreSQL 9.2.1 can store Large Object bigger than 2GB?

Tags: postgresql

I am totally new to PostgreSQL and database, and trying to do some tests about the large object.

I just found that 8GB file could be saved to Postgres.

However the document says the max for large object (`pg_largeobject` storage) is 2GB.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/lo-intro.html

Am I missing something here?

Select `version()` shows:

> PostgreSQL 9.2.1 on x86_64-unknow-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4), 64-bit

here is my code in case you are interested:

```
private long insertLargeObject(UsSqlSession session, FileEntity fileEntity) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    LargeObjectManager lobj = getLargeObjectAPI(session);

    long oid = lobj.createLO();
    LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.WRITE);

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileEntity.getFile())){
        int bufSize = 0x8FFFFFF;
        byte buf[] = new byte[bufSize];
        int s = 0;
        int tl = 0;
        while( (s = fis.read(buf, 0, bufSize)) > 0 ) {
            obj.write(buf, 0, s);
            tl += s;
        }
    }

    obj.close();
    return oid;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The size of the `pg_largeobject` is 11GB, and `pg_largeobject_metadata` says there is one line which means only one large object exists.

```
select sum(length(lo.data)) 
from pg_largeobject lo 
where lo.loid=1497980;
```

returns `4378853347`.

**UPDATE:**

```
public File findLargeObject(UsSqlSession session, long oid) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    LargeObjectManager lobj = getLargeObjectAPI(session);
    LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.READ);

    int bufSize = 0x8FFFFFF;
    byte buf[] = new byte[bufSize];
    int s = 0;
    int tl=0;

    File file = new File("e:/target-file");
    try(FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)){

        while( (s = obj.read(buf, 0, bufSize)) > 0 ){
            output.write(buf, 0, s);
            tl += s;
        }
        output.flush();
    }

    obj.close();
    return file;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about this myself. Could you try something from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169309/get-size-of-large-object-in-postgresql-query) to check if it actually is 8 GB on the server side, just to be sure?

Comment: Yeah... if you're on 9.2 I'm not convinced the object is really the size you think, since all sizes are 32-bit signed integers. A 64-bit integer API for large objects is coming; I think it's in 9.3 but would need to double-check. **+1 thanks for including a proper version and the code in question**.

Comment: @jpmc26 The size of the pg_large_object is 11GB, and pg_largeobject_metadata says there is one line.

Comment: @jpmc26 `select sum(length(lo.data)) from pg_largeobject lo
where lo.loid=1497980;` returns `4378853347`. I will update the question.

Comment: Assuming that's bytes, that's roughly 4 GB. Sounds like something fishy is going on all around. (Notifying @CraigRinger because I am clearly out of my league. =) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct answer would be: "Your PostgreSQL is built with int64 support thus enabling you to write more then 2GB in one LO. You can have problems reading it though."

Try reading reply from Tom Lane there: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Large-objects-td2852592.html pay attention to random rant about "lo_seek64" and "lo_tell64" functions.

Comment: Good find... that's a reasonable explanation.

Comment: "Ouch.  Letting people write data to where they can't get it back from 
seems double-plus ungood. " by Robert Haas

Comment: @CraigRinger I just ran anothe test by writing and reading a 3GB file. Postgres jsut works fine. `select sum(length(lo.data)) from pg_largeobject lo where lo.loid=1497987;` returns `3350906766`.

Comment: Yes, but can you *actually get the data* with `loread`, `lo_lseek`, etc? There are no `bigint` versions of those.

Comment: @CraigRinger I can read it from Postgres. See my updated code for the reading.

Comment: @jpmc26 I see. So Pg's internally using the 64-bit API, you just can't read more than 2GB chunks or seek more than 2GB at a time because the SQL interface is limited to ints. Presumably `lo_tell` will give weird results or an integer overflow error too. Ugly, but workable. Nice work on the question and follow-up, wish I could upvote you more; ditto kworr for finding the appropriate reference. I'll see if I can get this fixed in PostgreSQL 9.4, it's ugly.