# Count file size in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have this simple table which I would like to use to store files.

```
CREATE TABLE table(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 FILE_NAME TEXT,
 FILE OID
)
;
```

Is there any way with SQL query to count the total size of the files into the table? Is this possible without function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of large object in PostgreSQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169309/get-size-of-large-object-in-postgresql-query)

Comment: In my case I prefer to use query not function? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

rzo is close but not quite right.

```
select file_name, pg_column_size(lo_get(oid)) from files;
```

Gives you the size in bytes.

If you want pretty printing:

```
select file_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_column_size(lo_get(oid))::numeric) from files;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the *total disk size* (disk usage), you could do something like:

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

Other queries to measure the size of relations can be found [in the PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)

Comment: Thanks, but I only need to get the size of the files into the table.