# In Postgreql, how to determine if a column in a postgres table is of LOB type and then how to find the size of the largest LOB value in a schema?

Tags: postgresql, blob, database-administration

Using Postgres 10.6.

My objective is to find the max size

If the datatype of a column in `oid`, I understand from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/largeobjects.html that it can be concluded to be an LOB column. Can I conclude that if the datatype of a column in not `oid`, then the column is not an LOB?

*If not*, how do I go about finding the LOB columns in the schema and their max size?

*If yes*, I found here ([Get size of large object in PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169309/get-size-of-large-object-in-postgresql-query)) how to find size of an LOB given an oid. The best approach I can think of as of now, to find the size of the largest LOB value in a schema, is to loop through all LOB rows in all tables, and take the max. Is there a better approach?

Comment: A `bytea` is a "LOB" as well (and the preferred type for this). The max size for that is 1GB

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion is not safe in either direction.  I can certainly create a column of type OID, and populate it with integers from a sequence, or from a random number generator, or from generate_series.  I could also create LOs, and stuff the resulting OIDs into columns of other types, like `int` (int are signed and so would overflow/wrap around eventually, but that would be a long way off), `bigint`, or even `text`.

It would not really make sense to do those things, but people sometimes do things that don't make sense.

Comment: I do not think there is a supported data type in PG of type `OID`. Instead, that is the object identifier. Please correct me if I am wrong. Additionally, it would be nice if you could provide an example to go with it.