# Postgres get field with maximum size in a column?

Tags: postgresql

The column contains images as blob I want to get the size of the image with the maximum size.
How can I get this??
I do `Select max(photo) from table;`

Comment: Ok, you want. What is the type of the `photo` column? There are at least two way to store binary data in the PostgreSQL: [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html) and [LOB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-funcs.html)

Comment: it is  a lob/oid

Comment: Iin this case `max(photo)` is nothing about the photo's size. Just only about ID.  Quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169309/get-size-of-large-object-in-postgresql-query#10171306

Comment: PS: Try to store photos in the `bytea` column. Yes I know some people who prefered to store 10 mb in `bmp` format in its VC. Actully [#uck them all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TyqtWUTj6M)

Comment: yes it does thanks a lot